# WebStorm IDE: How do I put the caret/cursor at the end of every line in a selection?

Tags: keyboard, text-editor, ide

In Sublime Text, there's a feature that you can select a block of text and hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and it places a cursor at the end of each of those lines.

[image: SublimeText Demo]

I am looking for something similar in [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). Sometimes it's just not feasible to go adding carets to every single line in a long file.

Comment: This is off topic IMO. While a good question (+1), this applies to all OS not just macOS.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (without already making assumptions about the one possible solution of editing all line endings at once)? Maybe using Find/Replace with regexps might solve your problem just as well.

Comment: @jbis It's one of those questions which is on topic on several SE sites. But with WebStorm running on macOS it's perfectly on topic on AD as well.

Comment: What do you mean by “a cursor st the end of each of those lines”? There is normally a cursor (an insertion point) at the end of a single line, only one line at a time. Are you trying to do a vertical selection of text, column oriented rather than row oriented? Try Option+dragging. By the way when searching for this kind of issue, search for IntelliJ as well as WebStorm, as both tools share the same roots and share much behavior.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've added a gif to the question, demonstrating the feature I'm looking for.

Comment: @nohillside it's possible that this is an XY problem as you've linked, but the point is that I'm searching for an IDE feature which I've found useful in several contexts. My intended question is whether the feature exists in WebStorm and if so, how to access it. Please let me know, or suggest edits to make that clearer in the question if possible?

Comment: @JBis yes this could be across different OS but since it's likely that the MacOS shortcut will be OS specific I thought it made sense to post in this form